# How to get last six months of store?

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, store

I want to filter my store with a `Month` value:

```
//On clicking the Last Six Months period button
onLsmClick: function () {
    var chart = Ext.widget('drawchart');
    var chartStore = this.getGraphDataStore();
    chartStore.clearFilter(true);

    chartStore.filter([{
        filterFn: function (item) {
            return (item.get('Month') >= ?????  && (item.get('Month') < ?????)
        }
    }]);
    chartStore.sync = true;
    chart.redraw();
    chart.refresh();
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Finding right month
chartStore.filterBy(function(record){
       var index = chart
       return record.getData().Month >= ???? && record.getData().Month < ????;
});

//Finding last 6 records
var count = chartStore.getCount();
chartStore.filterBy(function(record){
       var index = chartStore.find('Month', record.month, 0, false, true, true); //Get current index of record based on month
       return index >= count - 6;
});
```

Refer to this link in the docs
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filterBy